# Origin of the phrase אור וחושך משמשים בערבוביה

Tags: provenance

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.1.4.1&lang2=bi) teaches us that light and darkness were mingled before Creation (Genesis 1:4, Dibur Hamaschil וירא אלהים את האור כי טוב ויבדל):

> ראהו כי טוב, ואין נאה לו ולחושך שיהיו משתמשין בערבוביא

In Hebrew, that Rashi seems to have turned into a phrase:

> אור וחושך משמשים בערבוביה

I'd like to know if that full Hebrew phrase appears as is in Sifrut Chazal?

Comment: This is the closest in a Sefaria search - https://www.sefaria.org/Shmonah_Kvatzim.3.340.1?vhe=Rav_Kook_public_files&lang=bi